# How can i store a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have some buttons that create different inputs with jQuery and i want that the site store the inputs i create for the next time. I imagine that i have to use cookies (i'm learning jQuery and all this things now) but i didn't find something i can use.

I have something like this:

```
<button id="createbutton">Button</button>

<script>
$( "#createbutton" )
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    $( "#somethinginteresting" ).dialog( "open" ); //this creates an input with some parameters
  });
</script>
```

When i refresh the site, the button isn't there obviously, how can i do this? Thank you so much for reading! And sorry for my english!

Comment: what do you mean by `//this creates an input with some parameters`  What do you want to persist on fresh load??

Comment: Have you checked out the jquery cookie plugin? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie - sample code on the link

Comment: It creates an input, for example a textbox with some parameters using the dialog-form (jQuery). Like this: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form but instead of that, it creates an input with the parameters i want.

Comment: If you need to store something for next use, you must store the data into a database, server side. The user can delete the cookie, use another browser, another computer, ... you can't be sure that the data is always on the cookie. Futhermore, the data is not available for other user. I don't know if you need that functionnalitiy, but with cookie, you can't share the data.